# Email is not sent in scheduled flow

Tags: email, visual-workflow, email-alert

I have a scheduled flow that is set to run daily and it calls a subflow that sends an email (this is just an MVP).

When I manually run or debug the subflow, the email is sent (It's not allowed to manually run a scheduled parent flow). But when I activate both flows and wait for the scheduled flow to run, the rest of the flow is executed, but the email is not sent (E.g. the create record element works as expected). There is no error or warning even, the email is not sent.

Is there some kind of configuration I'm missing? (I have already set the deliverability to "All email")

In the [help documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.salesforce_vpm_guide.meta/salesforce_vpm_guide/vpm_designer_elements_action_email_flow.htm), the following is stated:

> At run time, the email isn’t sent until the interview’s transaction
>   completes. Transactions complete either when the interview finishes,
>   executes a Screen element, or executes a Wait element.

Does it mean an email cannot be sent using a scheduled flow at all?

[image]

The subflow:

[image]

Comment: I see some references [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/salesforce/comments/dq9gir/winter_20_scheduled_flow_and_send_email_action/) to the Automated user being the sender and getting caught in spam filters. How are you testing that the email is sent?

Comment: Oh My. It was the reason. But it was not even shown in my spam box, but when I used another email address I got the email.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Scheduled flows](https://jenwlee.com/2019/10/01/schedule-a-flow/) run as the **Automated Process User** as I had tested for this [question](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/289628/do-scheduled-flows-run-with-admin-permissions/289637#289637)

This means that the email in the email alert is sent as that Automated User with a sender email address of **noreply@salesforce.com** as noted [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/salesforce/comments/dq9gir/winter_20_scheduled_flow_and_send_email_action/)

This tends to get caught in spam filters or, as mentioned in the above link with gmail and your situation, completely blocked which can cause frustrations when testing as you noticed.

Comment: It was not even in my spam box, I just tried using a different email and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

May be company information time zone is different. Set this time zone according to your time zone.
setup --> company information --> set the time zone.

Comment: Welcome to SFSE.  Please take a moment to read [ask] and take the [tour].  The question already has an accepted answer related to spam filters.  Also, the OP states that the rest of the flow is executed, so timezone is not an issue.