# Send email notification to contact when posted to chatter

Tags: email, chatter, contact

I have an action in a scheduled flow, that post to chatter for a certain Contact. Previously, when I used the ID of a User instead of a Contact, when posted to chatter, an email was received.

Can I enable some setting for a Contact to receive an email alert when posted to chatter?

On a side note, I'm using the chatter feed since sending an email through a scheduled flow is not working as of [my previous question](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/298182/email-is-not-sent-in-scheduled-flow).

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

[Chatter](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=collab_setting_up.htm&type=5) is for your organization's *users*. You won't be able to have email notifications go out from a chatter post out of the box to your *contacts*. I think your best bet is to figure out the answer to your other question regarding why an email alert is not working.

> Connect, engage, and motivate users to collaborate and work efficiently across the organization regardless of their role or location.